# Send a private message on facebook

Tags: javascript, html, facebook, facebook-graph-api

I am able to send a private message to my facebook friend using belwo facebook API.

```
<html xmlns:fb="https://www.facebook.com/2008/fbml">
<body>
<script src="http://connect.facebook.net/en_US/all.js"></script>
<div id="fb-root"></div>
<script>
  FB.init({appId: '315462388662460', xfbml: true, cookie: true});

  FB.ui({
      method: 'send',
      link: 'https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=uia0PQy5ksg',
      });
 </script>
</body>
</html>
```

And everytime I run the above page it open a [UI](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2jIow.png) and then I have to enter my friend name and mesage and then click on Send

Since I only need to send this to just one friend, Is there any way that could just send a messge on the execution of avove script.(Without opening any UI and clicking on Send)

Comment: No, that is not possible. There is no API to send user-to-user messages.

Answer (score 2):

the [doc](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/sharing/reference/send-dialog) says that you can pass user-id of the recipient in the 'to' param.

have you tried ?

```
FB.ui({
      method: 'send',
      link: 'https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=uia0PQy5ksg',
      to: <user_id>
      });
```

Comment: This still wouldn't solve OP's criteria of __"Without opening any UI and clicking on Send"__.

Comment: you're right. Atleast it solves the entering friend's name every time problem. But otherwise, it's not possible to send a message using the webkit without opening a dialog.

Comment: +1 as I am able to add the app_id in to field and the username appears in the dialogue form. is it possible to send without openining a dialoug box.?

Comment: I'm afraid not.

Comment: this is the correct answer, and there is no other way. there is also no way to send messages without opening the ui, AND your friend has to authorize your app first - after that, you can use his app scoped id for the "to" parameter.

Answer (score 1):

Accordingly, with the documentation, you need to provide your call with `to:` parameter with the id of the user, but I don't know if this will prevent from message dialog appear

https://developers.facebook.com/docs/sharing/reference/send-dialog

Comment: +1 as I am able to add the app_id in to field and the username appears in the dialogue form. but still it is showing the dialouge box. is it possible to send without openining a dialoug box.?

Comment: maybe if you dig a bit more on the `display` parameter, and if is possible to customise it although I'm afraid it's not